# Docker compose host volume data not in container folder

Tags: ssl, docker, gitlab, letsencrypt, nextcloud

I am trying to add gitlab to my nextcloud vps. As usual, I have problems with the ssl certs. The container folder is empty, whereas the host folder isn't. The host content is not added to the container volume. The container folder is empty(`/etc/gitlab/ssl`).

```
version: '2'
services:
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

  letsencrypt-companion:
    image: alastaircoote/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: letsencrypt-companion
    volumes_from:
      - proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
    restart: always

  web:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nextcloud_webserver
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    links:
      - app
      - collabora
    volumes_from:
      - app
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${DOMAIN}
      - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nginx-proxy
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=${DOMAIN}
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}
networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

  app:
    image: nextcloud:fpm
    container_name: nextcloud_fpm
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./nextcloud/apps:/var/www/html/apps
      - ./nextcloud/config:/var/www/html/config
      - ./nextcloud/data:/var/www/html/data
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - ./nextcloud/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

  collabora:
    image: collabora/code
    container_name: collabora
    cap_add:
      - MKNOD
    environment:
      - domain=${DOMAIN}
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    container_name: gitlab
    restart: always
    hostname: ${GITDOMAIN}
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${GITDOMAIN}
      VIRTUAL_NETWORK: nginx-proxy
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 80
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${GITDOMAIN}
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: ${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
          external_url "https://${GITDOMAIN}"
          nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/fullchain.pem"
          nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/key.pem"
          # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
    volumes:
      - ./gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
      - ./gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - ./gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
      - /opt/nextcloud-docker/.examples/proxy/certs/${GITDOMAIN}:/etc/gitlab/ssl:rw
    networks:
      - proxy-tier

networks:
  proxy-tier:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

> 2017/08/19 09:26:17 [emerg] 6465#0:
>   BIO_new_file("/etc/gitlab/ssl/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL:
>   error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or
>   directory:fopen('/etc/gitlab/ssl/fullchain.pem','r')
>   error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

`docker inspect gitlab`

```
{
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/opt/nextcloud-docker/.examples/proxy/certs/domain",
                "Destination": "/etc/gitlab/ssl",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }

"Volumes": {
                "/etc/gitlab": {},
                "/etc/gitlab/ssl": {},
                "/var/log/gitlab": {},
                "/var/opt/gitlab": {}
            },
```

Maybe this `/etc/gitlab` masks the `/etc/gitlab/ssl`. I read about containers masking host files, this is all very confusing and new for me. How do I go about debugging this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out gitlab just displays nginx error.log always when starting. So ssl certificate was already there and working. I still had problems configuring the port to work with jwilder nginx-proxy. So this is how my last config looks like and works:

symlink the .env with `gitlab-docker$ln -s ../.env .env`

official docker-compose.yml of nextcloud:
`./docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

  letsencrypt-companion:
    image: alastaircoote/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: letsencrypt-companion
    volumes_from:
      - proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
    restart: always

  web:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nextcloud_webserver
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    links:
      - app
      - collabora
    volumes_from:
      - app
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${DOMAIN}
      - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nginx-proxy
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=${DOMAIN}
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

  app:
    image: nextcloud:fpm
    container_name: nextcloud_fpm
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./nextcloud/apps:/var/www/html/apps
      - ./nextcloud/config:/var/www/html/config
      - ./nextcloud/data:/var/www/html/data
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - ./nextcloud/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

  collabora:
    image: collabora/code
    container_name: collabora
    cap_add:
      - MKNOD
    environment:
      - domain=${DOMAIN}
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

networks:
  proxy-tier:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

`./gitlab-docker/docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    container_name: gitlab
    restart: always
    hostname: ${GITDOMAIN}
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${GITDOMAIN}
      VIRTUAL_NETWORK: nginx-proxy
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 80
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${GITDOMAIN}
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: ${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://${GITDOMAIN}'
        nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/fullchain.pem"
        nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/key.pem"
        nginx['listen_port'] = 80
        nginx['listen_https'] = false
        nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {  "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https", "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on" }
        # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
    ports:
      - '3022:22'
    volumes:
      - gitcerts:/etc/gitlab/ssl:ro
      - ../gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
      - ../gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - ../gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
    networks:
      - proxy-tier

networks:
  proxy-tier:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy

volumes:
  gitcerts:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /opt/nextcloud-docker/.examples/proxy/certs/${GITDOMAIN}
      o: bind
```

- Notice the named volume to access the certs for gitlab(`docker volume
  ls` to list volumes, and `docker volume inspect $name` to display the
  mountpoint, which in my case is
  `/var/lib/docker/volumes/gitlabdocker_gitcerts/_data`).
- Also notice the specific listen directives for gitlab, credits to those below.

Credits:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1307
- https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/309#issuecomment-163556850
  (for explaining how jwilder/nginx-proxy works)